# Warning inconsistent extent when add shapefile

Tags: arcmap, layers, extents

When I add a shapefile of a small city into a blank map, I get `Warning, inconsistent extent!`.

After carefully checking, I found this issue may cause by the unnormal layer extent:

```
Top: 1.#INF00 dd                  
Left:-1.#INF00 dd
Right:179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 dd
Bottom:-179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 dd
```

Because I am a green hand in ArcMap, I do not know how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is an actual ESRI Shapefile and not a different format?

Comment: @inc42 Hi, how can I identify whether it is an actual ESRI Shapefile? I can see and edit it in the content panel.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still not clear about the cause of this issue, I find an easy solution. All we need to do is to export the problematic layer into a new layer in the table of content, then the extent will be fixed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your shapefile and run the recalculate feature extent tool on that shapefile. Or right click the shapefile from the catalog pane > properties > Feature Extent Tab > recalculate the feature extent. Do you get different/updated values now and does this fix the issue?